# Updated MVC 1 Project and actionlinks misdirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I updated a rather plain MVC 1.0 project to MVC 2.0 and now all the actionlinks misdirect.  They all erroneously start on .../Home.mvc/....  This project was about as close to Hello World! as it gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, that was fast but... answer:

The upgrade tool actually did change my routes in the Global.asax

```
    routes.MapRoute(
      "Default",
      "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
      new { action = "Index", id = "" }
    );
```

Removing the ".mvc" fixed it.

I would normally have checked there first but I assumed (silly me) that the upgrade utility would not just go crazy on my routing.

Edit:  The ".mvc" is necessary for deploying to server 2003 IIS 6.0, but will not work in my dev environment on a windows 7.  So what I had to do was to remove the .mvc while coding then add it back prior to deployment for each deploy.